# Django: Redirect after posting a comment

Tags: django, django-forms, django-comments

I am trying to redirect the user back to the page where the comment was posted. I found this [post on Django's site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#redirecting-after-the-comment-post) but I am doing something wrong because it won't redirect back.

Where should the input be placed to have it properly redirected?

```
{% load comments i18n %}
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {% if next %}<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />{% endif %}
  {% for field in form %}
    {% if field.is_hidden %}
      {{ field }}
    {% else %}
      {% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url proposal proposal.id %}" />
      <p
        {% if field.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}
        {% ifequal field.name "honeypot" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}
         {% ifequal field.name "name" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}
         {% ifequal field.name "email" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}
         {% ifequal field.name "url" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}
         {% ifequal field.name "title" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}>
        <!-- {{ field.label_tag }}  -->{{ field }}
      </p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <p class="submit">
    <!-- <button><input type="submit" name="post" value="{% trans "Send" %}" /></button> -->
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    <!-- <input type="submit" name="preview" class="submit-preview" value="{% trans "Preview" %}" /> -->
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: looks right to me -- are you supplying a next value? Try testing with a hard coded next.

Comment: I am not. I missed that line, and thought <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url proposal proposal.id %}" /> would redirect it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see that second one. I'd definitely start by hard coding **one** value into the form to start narrowing down the problem.

Comment: This question may show my inexperience, but how/where do I define "next" in my code? Here is the comment code for a Picture object's page: gist.github.com/4ea34b6f559a15c91d05 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't need to check for **next** variable in your template. You could try changing:

```
{% if next %}<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />{% endif %}
```

to just:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/added/comment/page/" />
```

In case you use views.py, redirecting from there seems more obvious, at least for me, as it helps keep the concern away from the template:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
HttpResponseRedirect("/path/to/redirect")
```

Comment: Arbie, thanks for the comment. I think you are onto it. The one question I have is how/where do I define 'next'? Here is a sample of my comment section for a picture object: gist.github.com/4ea34b6f559a15c91d05  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: For mine, I just used a function that rendered the same page the comment form is on.
 <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url picture picture.id %}" />

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [axel22's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560218/317217) is that it requires a change to each template that requires the comment form - if you have multiple object types that can be commented on, this is not DRY.

Unfortunately, I'm also still looking for an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `{% render_comment_form for object %}` tag in your template, just add something like `{% url object's_named_view object.id as next %}` or wrap it with `{% with object.get_absolute_url as next %}` ... `{% endwith %}` construction.

Answer (score 0):

See my solution here: [Django: Redirect to current article after comment post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123206/django-redirect-to-current-article-after-comment-post/24210053#24210053)

It basically uses a view that's triggered by the comment post url which redirects back to the original referrer page.