# update url after returning a specific view with django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a django app samplesubmission with two different views. The index view (`localhost:8000/samplesubmission/`) lists the last 5 samples and an add view (`localhost:8000/samplesubmission/add/`), which adds a new sample. If everything works, I return the index view.

```
return index(request)
```

This works fine, only the url in the browser still says `localhost:8000/samplesubmission/add/` so, if I hit reload, I am already at the form to add a new sample...

Just wondering, how to change the url in the browser.

Sorry, for not presenting a minimal working example, but I am not sure, what I will need for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `redirect()` for that:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

It's shortcut method which will redirect (big surprise ;) ) user to desired view.

Comment: thanks, I used `redirect('/samplesubmission')` now, because I get an error just redirecting to the index view with `redirect('index')`, but this helps already.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to redirect the page after the sample is added. Django has redirect methods

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
HttpResponseRedirect("/path/to/redirect")
```

This question has some more details [Django: Redirect after posting a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169715/django-redirect-after-posting-a-comment)