# Django comments change success url

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I would like to change the URL you are redirected to when django posts a comment successfully - I'd much rather be taken to the page where the comment has been posted to, rather than the current redirect to a 'thanks for your comment' URL. Is there a place I can override this in django? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: Redirect to current article after comment post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123206/django-redirect-to-current-article-after-comment-post)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a hidden field called next to your comment form with the value of the url you'd like to re-direct to after the form has been posted.

Example from the docs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url my_comment_was_posted %}" />
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#redirecting-after-the-comment-post

Comment: Excellent - thanks a lot, had totally missed that on the docs!