# Django redirect after comment post

Tags: python, django, redirect

Im new to Django, and im trying to understand, why my code instead of redirect to :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/object/2/
```

redirect me to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/object/2/?c=14
```

Where is the code, that adds this parameters?

Template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% get_comment_form for object as comment_form %}

    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form.comment }}
        {{ comment_form.content_type }}
        {{ comment_form.object_pk }}
        {{ comment_form.timestamp }}
        {{ comment_form.security_hash }}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}" />
        <input type="submit" value="post comment" />
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>Please <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">log in</a> to leave a comment.</p>
{% endif %}
```

views.py:

```
class realiz_photo_view(DetailView):

    template_name = 'realization/realiz_photo.html'
    model = realiz_photo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(realiz_photo_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = RealizationForm()
        return context
```

urls.py:

```
url(r"^comments/", include("django.contrib.comments.urls")),
url(r'^object/', include('realization.urls')),
```

realization/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', realiz_photo_view.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: can u share comment_form_target  url in urls.py

Answer (score 0):

See my solution here: Django: [Redirect to current article after comment post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123206/django-redirect-to-current-article-after-comment-post/24210053#24210053)

It basically uses a view that's triggered by the comment post url which redirects back to the original referrer page.

Comment: @Corey_C TY for your answer, but your link is broken.

Comment: @Harkonnen sorry, I fixed the link.